# MVC 3 traditional database or dataset to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ms-access

I have legacy code that I am slowly moving to C# MVC. How would I create a dropdownlist from a data table or dataset?  I do not want to create properties and loop through a list because I have too many ancient MS Access queries to deal with.

CONTROLLER:

```
 using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            string commandstring = "select column1 from table1";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandstring, Connection);
            Connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand = command;
            da.Fill(ds, "data1");
            Connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You should separate out the dataaccess from the controller into a repository and return an Object (not a dataset) to your controller. From there, it's relatively easy to create a ViewModel that the Dropdownlist can consume.  If you show a bit more of your code, it will help to tailor the solution.

Comment: I just want to bind the dataset to a normal html dropdownlist.

Comment: MVC doesn't have controls that let you "just bind a dataset". See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As George stated, I would suggest moving the domain logic into a data access layer and using entities to hold your objects that were returned from a query. You can use [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which allows you to use raw SQL queries and have the results mapped to models. Its performance is same as `SqlDataReader`. Here is an extension method that will take a list of models and turn them into a dropdown list.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T, TTextProperty, TValueProperty>(this IEnumerable<T> instance, Func<T, TTextProperty> text, Func<T, TValueProperty> value, Func<T, bool> selectedItem = null)
{
    return instance.Select(t => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = Convert.ToString(text(t)),
        Value = Convert.ToString(value(t)),
        Selected = selectedItem != null ? selectedItem(t) : false
    });
}
```

Then you can use the code like ...

```
var list = SomeQuery();
list.ToSelectList(x => x.Name, x => x.id, x => x.id == selectedId);
```